# Select distinct of a date along with other fields from a table

Tags: sql-server-2000

In the table 'Emplyoee' there are two fields-JoinDate and EmployeeName.

All Data contains in Emplyoee table is as follows:

```
JoinDate      | EmployeeName
------------------------
02-12-2009   Vijay

03-12-2009   Binoy

03-12-2009   Rahul
```

My select query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT JoinDate,EmployeeName FROM Emplyoee
```

I got the Result as follows:

```
JoinDate   | EmployeeName
------------------------
02-12-2009   Vijay
03-12-2009   Binoy
03-12-2009   Rahul
```

But i need the result as follows:

```
JoinDate   | EmployeeName
------------------------
02-12-2009   Vijay
03-12-2009   Binoy(first employee joined on this date)
```

Comment: Logically....you would need the time info too...to get to the first employee on the same day

Comment: And how would you break the tie when 2+ employees start at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select the first employee *alphabetically* that joined on each date:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT mydates.JoinDate, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeName FROM Employee e2 WHERE e2.JoinDate=mydates.JoinDate ORDER BY EmployeeName)
 FROM Employee mydates
```